# Referencing data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, rdbms

I have three simple entities :

Course is like a Book, a sell-able product. The Course entity represents a course and has various properties, such as Duration, Fees, Author, Type and so on.

```
Course 
{
    int Id;
    string Title;
}
```

A topic is like an individual page in a Book, it has the actual learning content. A topic may appear in multiple courses.

```
Topic
{
    int Id;
    string Title;
}
```

In context of a book, Quiz is also an individual page which holds questions instead of learning content. Again a Quiz may be appear into multiple courses.

```
Quiz
{
    int Id;
    string Title;
}
```

Now that i have individual Topics and Quizzes i wish to have a table that will assemble Topics and Quizzes into a Book. Consider this table as Table of Contents in a book. Below is a outline of what i am expecting it to look like :

```
CourseContents
{
     int CourseId; // Foreign-Key to Courses.Id
     int Page;     // Foreign-Key to either Topic.Id or Quiz.Id
     int SNo;      // Sequence of this page (topic/quiz) in the course, much like page number in a book.
     int Type      // Type of the page i.e, Quiz or Topic. 
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in RDBMS ?

#### Attempt to Solution

One approach i am looking at is creating a table to create a unique identifier for a given Course Item. Then use it in mapping tables Courses-Topics and Courses-Quizzes. Please refer below :

```
CourseContents
{
    int Id;        // CourseContentId Primary-Key for this table
    int CourseId;  // Foreign key to Course.Id
    int SNo;       // Serial number of an item in this course;
}

CourseTopics
{
    int TopicId;             // Foreign-Key to Topics.Id
    int CourseContentsId;    // Foreign-Key to CourseContents.Id
}

CourseQuizzes
{
    int QuizId;               // Foreign-Key to Quizzes.Id
    int CourseContentsId;     // Serial number of the quiz in the course
}
```

**Problem :** The CourseContentId represent a particular position ( of Topic/Quiz ) in a particular course. Two items cannot occupy same position in a course sequence, hence one CourseContentId must be associated with just one item in either CourseTopics or CourseQuizzes. How can we put unique constraint on CourseContentsId across two tables ?

**Further Addition**

The above said problem can be solved by adding a ContentType column in CourseContents, CourseTopics and CourseQuizzes column. Then applying **Check constraint** on the tables to make sure :

- CourseContents has a unique combination of CourseContentId and ContentType.
- CourseTopics & CourseQuizzes must have the same content Type across.
- Adding a Foreign key referencing CourseContents(CourseContentId, ContentType) in CourseTopics & CourseQuizzes tables.

This will ensure that a CourseContentId will not appear in both the tables.

Comment: You have another table, a link table *(also known as a mapping table, or an associative table, or an adjacency list)*, with two principle columns : CourseID and QuizID.  This table can then link any quiz to any course, allowing a `0..many` : `0..many` relationship.  *(One quiz can relate to 0..many courses, and one course can relate to 0.many quizzes.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Actually Topics and Quizes have to be composed into a Course. Which means i am looking for a single table referencing two different tables i.e. Course Contents are associated with Topic and Quiz tables.

Comment: That's too vague, please show a material example in your question.  *(Of a full set of associations that you are trying to map.)*

Comment: That's the problem i have, two tables storing two different object types. But finally all those two types are to be assembled into one.

Comment: ***That's too vague***, please show ***a material example in your question***. (Of a full set of associations that you are trying to map.). *(Edit your question, and write out a real, categorical, material, example of what an example course, topic, quiz structure would actually look like.  Not an abstract description, a **material** example.)*

Comment: Seems like it is 1:many -- One Course : Many CourseContents.  To need many:many, you imply that some of the same contents is used in multiple Courses.

Comment: @RickJames You are right the relationship between Course and Course content is One-to-Many. What i meant was relationship between Course and Topics/Quiz is many-to-many. CourseContents isn't an existing table, but a desired outcome.

Comment: Dear moderators, can you please remove the hold from the question ?? I have found the way that worked for me and would like to share here as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE CourseContents (
  CourseContentsId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CourseContentType CHAR(1) CHECK (CourseContentType IN ('T', 'Q')),
  CourseId INTEGER REFERENCES Courses(Id),
  SNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UniqueCourseContent UNIQUE (CourseId, SNo),
  CONSTRAINT UniqueCourseContentMapping UNIQUE (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType),
);
```

Course Contents table generates a Unique Id ( CourseContentsId ) for each CourseId and SNo combination, which can then be referenced in the Topics & Quizzes table. As there are two different tables (Topics & Quizzes), we introduce another column that identifies the Type of the Content(Topic/Quiz) that it is linked to. By using a composite UNIQUE constraint on CourseContentsId & CourseContentType we make sure that each entry can be linked to only one content type.

```
CREATE TABLE CourseTopics (
  CourseContentsId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CourseContentType CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'T' CHECK (CourseContentType = 'T'),
  TopicId INTEGER REFERENCES Topics(Id),
  PRIMARY KEY (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType),
  FOREIGN KEY (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType) REFERENCES CourseContents (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType)
);
```

Course Topics table is mapping table between Topics and Courses ( we have many-to-many relationship between Courses & Topics tables ). The foreign & primary key to CourseContents table ensures that we'll have one entry for each CourseContent ( in other words Course & SNo ). The table restricts CourseContentType to only accept 'T', which means a given CourseContentId must have Content Type of Topic inorder to be linked with a Topic.

```
CREATE TABLE CourseQuizzes (
  CourseContentsId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CourseContentType CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Q' CHECK (CourseContentType = 'Q'),
  QuizId INTEGER REFERENCES Quizzes(Id),
  PRIMARY KEY (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType),
  FOREIGN KEY (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType) REFERENCES CourseContents (CourseContentsId, CourseContentType)
);
```

Similar to the Topics table we now create CourseQuizzes table. Only difference is here we have CourseContentType 'Q'.

Finally to simplify querying, we can create a view that joins these tables together. For e.g, the view below will list : CourseId, SNo, ContentType, TopicId, QuizId. In context of a book, with this view you can get what's on a particular Page Number (SNo) of a given book (Course), with type of content on the page (Topic or Quiz) and the id of the content.

```
CREATE VIEW CourseContents_All AS 
SELECT CourseContents.CourseId, CourseContents.SNo, CourseContents.CourseContentType , CourseTopics.Id, CourseQuizzes.Id
FROM CourseContents
LEFT JOIN CourseTopics ON (CourseContents.CourseContentsId = CourseTopics.CourseContentsId)
LEFT JOIN CourseQuizzes ON (CourseContents.CourseContentsId = CourseQuizzes.CourseContentsId);
```

The advantages that i feel with this approach are :

1. This structure follows inheritance, which means we can support more content types by just adding another table and modifying CourseContentType Check constraint in CourseContents table.
2. For a given CourseId and SNo. i also know the content type. This certainly will help in the application code.

> Note : Check constraint does not work in MySQL. For it one needs to use Triggers instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The CourseContentId represent a particular position ( of Topic/Quiz ) in a particular course.

```
CourseTopics
{
    int TopicId;             // Foreign-Key to Topics.Id

    int CourseContentsId;  -- first of 3-part FK
    int Page;              -- added
    int SNo;               -- added
    PRIMARY KEY(TopicId, CourseContentsId, Page, SNo), -- for JOINing one way
    INDEX      (CourseContentsId, Page, SNo, TopicId)  -- for JOINing the otehr way
}
```

Meanwhile, ...

I *guess* that your main Problem is embodied in this one line:

> int Page;     // Foreign-Key to either Topic.Id or Quiz.Id

That is impractical.  The solution is to have a *single* table for `Topic` and `Page` and differentiate from there.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't understand your answer. Can you please provide a little detail on how this works ? Adding the structure for CourseQuizzes will be more helpful and appreciable. Thnx

Comment: @PraveenRai - Do you need to relate a specific page in a course to a topic?  Or do you need a general link that says "somewhere in this course topic X is discussed"?

Comment: The course table does not really store all the pages of a course. Consider it as laminated book. It's just the cover that holds information such as Fees, Author etc. The Topic is more like the individual page in that book, which actually has the content (accessible only to authorized users). We also have Quizzes and much like a Topic they also appear at some position, much like in a book you have some 12 pages teaching you something and then the 13th page throws few questions. The tricky part is that the course is collection of Topics/Quizzes in certain order.

Comment: I've updated the same explanation in my original question.

Comment: @PraveenRai - I updated my Answer with what I think is the "problem", plus my suggested solution.