# EF Core multiple realationship of a single column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core 3.1 and I have five Models: `Plant`, `Area`, `Unit`, `Schema`, and `EntitiesSchema`.
In the `EnititiesSchema`, the `EntityId` may be a foreign key of `Plant`(PlantId), `Area`(AreaId), `Unit`(UnitId) tables.
How to handle this optional Relationship between these tables?

Thanks

```
public class EntitiesSchema
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int SchemaId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Schema Schema { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you mens like having a foreign key that can be null? If so, I think you can just make the `EntityId` nullable

Comment: No, my foreign key may be related multiple tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't relate a foreign key to multiple tables. But you can put another property named `EntityType` to store the type of entity. Then on the client-side, you can handle it. The `EntityType` can be an enum type.

Another approach is that storing "EntitesSchemaId" in the `Plant`, `Area`, `Unit`, etc models and relate them to the `EntitiesSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediary entity to map to different entity types. :

```
Public class EntityMap
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string EntityKind {get;set;} // could be "Plant", "Area", "Unit", "Schema"
}

public class Plant 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string EntityKind {get;set;} = "Plant";
}

public class EntitySchema
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public int EntityMapId {get;set;}
     public EntityMap Map {get;set;}
}
```

The logic to read data from individual schema, has to be implemented in the client,but common properties of the entities can be added in EntityMap.
Here's a similar answer you might want to reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649452/7491048